# Expressing a Non-linear ODE in a Way That It Becomes Linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example, suppose I have the following ODEs:
$$(y')^2-2y'+1=0\tag{1}\label{eq:ODE1}\,;$$ 
 $$(y')^2=0\tag{2}\label{eq:ODE2}\,,$$
where $y$ is dependent on $x$.

Then are they linear?

---

Immediately I would think not since they are not of the form $a_n(x)y^{(n)}+\cdots+a_1(x)y'=a_0(x)$ (and [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%5E2-2y(x)%27%2B1%3D0)[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%5E2%3D0) seems to agree with this). However, if I rewrite $\eqref{eq:ODE1}$ and $\eqref{eq:ODE2}$ as $$(y'-1)^2=0\,;\quad y'=1\tag{1*}$$ and $$y'=0\,,\tag{2*}$$ now both equations are apparently linear.

---

What am I misunderstanding here? As far as I can tell it may be one of two things: either the first two equations are linear and there is a mistake with how WolframAlpha obtains this result or how I entered the equations, or my rearrangement was wrong and the pairs of equations are not equivalent.

I can't seem to find any similar questions on here or anywhere else so forgive me if this is a duplicate.

Comment: you were able to reduce non-linear ode to linear, which is possible in some specific cases but not possible in general. In your case linear ode is equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing a nonlinear equation to a linear one can be quite a delicate issue.  Yes, in your case, as Vasya observed, they are equivalent in the sense that any solution of the one is a solution of the other, and vice versa.  But consider the case of a Bernoulli equation
$$
\tag{1}
y' = \sqrt{y},
$$
which can be reduced, via substitution $u = \sqrt{y}$, to the (certainly linear) equation
$$
u' = 2.
\tag{2}
$$
$u(x) = 2x$ is a solution of $(2)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and it corresponds to $y(x) = 4x^2$, which is a solution of $(1)$ only for $x \in [0, \infty)$.  On the other hand, $y \equiv 0$ is a solution of $(1)$ which does not correspond to any solution of $(2)$.  And,
$$
y(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ for } x < 0 \\
4x^2 & \text{ for } x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
is yet another solution of $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you. So in terms of classification, would I say, for example, that (y')^2=0 is non-linear?

Comment: **I** would say $(y')^2 = 0$ is nonlinear.